# Display rich media flash banner ad in html 5

Tags: html, flash

I've created a rich media flash banner ad—one that is more than a simple, self-contained swf file. It starts out as a simple 300x250 pixel banner ad, but when a button initiated by the user is pressed, it expands to 500 pixels wide and displays static images as well as plays a video.

It is comprised of multiple swf files, including a swf for the 300x250 portion, a swf for the 500x250 portion, and a swf shell file. You must play the shell file in order for the ad to play as a cohesive unit. In addition to the multiple swf files, the ad is also comprised of actionscript files, an flv file, and images, all of which are external, i.e., not embedded in the swf files.

I need to embed the ad in a webpage so that it can be easily viewed by anyone. I have tried this, but only the bits of the ad containing vector art will load. Nothing else, including the images or video, will even display. (All of the components have been uploaded to the server we use, so I know that a missing component is not the problem.)

The coding I have used is for embedding a single swf file, which seems to be the incorrect way to go about this. Does anyone know of a way to embed this type banner ad?

Answer (score 0):

You should have received some instructions how to embed the ad. Usually expanding ads need some javascript and specific html markup. Also, make sure the path to the files (video, images, swfs) is correct.

On the other hand, actionscript files are not needed - they are only required for compiling the swf file from source (fla most likely).